# How to set baseURL of $fetch in nuxt3 plugin (make custom fetch)

Tags: vue.js, url, fetch, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I made a customFetch plugin in 'cutomFetch.js' plugin file.

I have to pass a different baseURL depending on environment.

for example,

```
1) local

-> https:// localhost:3000

2) Verification site before final distribution (dev branch code)

-> https:// 123. com

3) commercial site (master branch code)

-> https:// abc. com
```

But, if you write the code as follows, when I refresh a page, an `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL` error occurs.

(It does not occur when moving pages using a router.)

When I checked, it said that the `referer` value does not exist.

How can I solve this issue...?

```js
import { ofetch } from 'ofetch'
// Nuxt uses ofetch to expose globally the $fetch helper for making HTTP requests within your Vue app or API routes.

const fetcher = ofetch.create({
  // set options...
})

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
  const customFetch = async (request, options) => {
    const baseURL = process.server ?
      new URL((nuxtApp?.ssrContext?.event?.node?.req?.headers?.referer)).origin :
      window.location.origin

    const response = await fetcher.raw(request, {
      ...options,
      baseURL
    })

    return response._data
  }

  nuxtApp.provide('customFetch', customFetch)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add URL to environment variable.

#### .env file

```
APP_URL=abc.com
```

#### Add runtime config to nuxt.config.ts

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
   // Other configs
   
   // Add runtime config
   runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      appUrl: process.env.APP_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
  },
}
```

#### Using in your plugin

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
        const config = useRuntimeConfig()
        const customFetch = async (request, options) => {
            const baseURL = config.public.appUrl

            const response = await fetcher.raw(request, {
                ...options,
                baseURL
            })

            return response._data
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I have to add app_url in 3 versions in my project. (master, local and 'dev' site: Verification site before final distribution (dev branch code)) I don't know how to distinguish master and dev, so I used `window.location.origin`(to read in client side) and `useNuxtApp().srrContext...referer`(to read in server side). How can I do?

Comment: For each environment you can set different APP_URL.

Comment: Thank you. But, how can I set baseURL? I cant know if it is 'https://dev.com' or 'https://master.com'.

Comment: @LSS if statement. e.g if(baseURL === 'dev.com')......

Comment: To set baseURL you can create file .env as I answer early